Enterprise Territory Management for Sales & service process
I have a requirement where salesforce has to be implemented for a business which will happen in 25+ countries. Just wanted to know if i have to go with region+country wide Roles and sharing rules or can i leaverage Enterprise territory management + sharing rules on territories to manage data sharing and assigning accounts? Can i also use ETM for managing service which will again happen in 15+ countries? Thanks in advance.

You should check the documentation and Trailhead modules to determine if Sales Territories (formerly Enterprise Territory Mgmt) meets your requirements.

It's depends on your requirements. But you can aware of below things before going to choose.

You can able to use Role Hierarchy when your business will like to view/control the record access on structured basis. Like You have a sales director whom will have to edit/transfer access of his under teammates records. So this kind of organization structured will applying to record level access also in "Role Hierarchy" based design.

In Here,  All the user's are configured based on his position (1 role - 1 user) and other role access are enabled based on sharing rules.


Example:


In other hand Territory Management record access are shared based on "Territory" like geography, products into various users. In here, One user can able to available in more then one territory. As it's said it's a kind of complex design model.

It's allows the user to access from various territories based on that user presence.


Example:


But please note, Following one business model is always good and ease
to understood the record sharing model.

Thanks.

Thanks for the detailed info Raj
